# Next-auth get token for Github REST API

Tags: typescript, github, next.js, github-api, next-auth

I want to implement user login and access some user data via the [Github REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest?apiVersion=2022-11-28) (eg. repository, issues).

Then I successfully implemented a login feature, but the Github REST API requires a token to access its endpoints. I checked the session using `getServerSession(authOptions)` and obtained some information, but not the token (as shown below).

```json
"session": {
  "user": {
    "name": "UserName",
    "email": "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    "image": "https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx/xxxxx"
  }
}
```

I tried some solutions on StackOverflow but none of them worked for me. 
Is there somebody who can help me? Thansk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in next.js Discrod server by someone's help. 
docs: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#sign-in-callback

```js
export const authOptions : NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: ...,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt", // add this
  },
  providers: [...],
  // add two callback functions following
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken as string;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    }
  },
};
```

Then for typescript, you need to write this in "types/next-auth.d". 
docs: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript

```
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    accessToken: string;
    expires: string;
    user: {
      address: string
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**